# Tuple metavar value for positional argument with nargs > 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

It seems that setting a tuple as a `metavar` for positional argument and requesting help does not work:

```py
import argparse


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('size', type=int, nargs=2, help='size', metavar=('w', 'h'))

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

This produces an error when called as `prog.py --help`. The error differs between Python3 versions (I tried 3.5, 3.6, 3.8) and includes `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 1)` or `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, tuple found`. [See live example on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/eY7n99zMNEB3RwZN).

For optional arguments, all is good:

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--size', type=int, nargs=2, help='size', metavar=('w', 'h'))

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

[Live example on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/aNkJsJGYK97wN1KM).

**Is my code invalid, or did I find a bug in Python implementation?**

Please note that simply parsing the arguments works as expected.

Comment: Isn't `metavar` only intended for optional arguments?

Comment: Not only, please see the example from [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#metavar). However, tuple metavar is used only for optional arg in the following example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Last part of the traceback is

```
/usr/lib/python3.6/argparse.py in _format_action_invocation(self, action)
    550         if not action.option_strings:
    551             default = self._get_default_metavar_for_positional(action)
--> 552             metavar, = self._metavar_formatter(action, default)(1)
    553             return metavar
    554
```

So yes, it's specifically occurring with `positionals` (empty `option_strings`).  The `metavar, = ...` assignment only works with the RHS returns one item.  With your `metavar` it's returning a 2.

Usage displays ok

```
In [36]: parser.print_usage()                                                   
usage: ipython3 [-h] w h
```

It does look like a bug.

The `(1)` argument tells the function is should return a 1 element tuple:

```
metavar, = self._metavar_formatter(action, default)(1)
```

I suspect the issue has been raised already in Python bug/issues.  I'll look for it later.

---

Instead of metavar, you could just as well use two positional arguments:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('w', type=int)
parser.add_argument('h', type=int)
```

This has been a known bug for a long time - but so far no action:

https://bugs.python.org/issue14074

> argparse allows nargs>1 for positional arguments but doesn't allow metavar to be a tuple

Comment: Thanks for this. My original code already had two positional arguments and my finding was due to a refactoring (I wanted my positional arg to be handled just like an optional one). I guess I will stay with that.

Answer (score 2):

Following [hpaulj's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58546660/4518341), here's another workaround using `action='append'`:

```
for name in 'width', 'height':
    parser.add_argument('size', type=int, help=name, metavar=name[0], action='append')
args = parser.parse_args(['4', '3'])
print(args)
parser.print_help()
```

Output:

```
Namespace(size=[4, 3])
usage: test.py [-h] w h

positional arguments:
  w           width
  h           height
```

Comment: I have been using `argparse` a LONG time, and I was unaware that a) one can use "append" with positionals, and b) one can give the the same positional name multiple times with different help/metavar.  Great suggestion!